# How to compare dates in Linux

Tags: linux

My so.txt contains below line:

```
PRE 2022-03-16/
```

Date is = 2022-03-16

```
awsdate= cut -c 5-14 so.txt
 sysdates=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
 echo $sysdates
 if [[ "$awsdate" == "$sysdates" ]] ;
then
    echo "dates are matching"
else
    echo "dates are not matching"
fi
```

Output:

```
2022-03-16
2022-03-16
dates are not matching
```

With above script I am trying to compare dates in Linux. Although the dates are same I am still getting dates are not matching. Why is this?

Comment: what shell is this? did you run it through shellcheck.net already?

Comment: Possibly useful: [Unix & Linux: How do I add X days to date and get new date?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49053/114401)

Comment: Do you have a space or newline at the end of one of the dates?

Comment: Your code doesn't match your output, by the way. You're missing a print statement for `awsdate` it looks like.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote any helpful answer you receive, and mark an answer as correct if it solves your problem. Upvoting is the motivation that keeps answerers answering. :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a quoting error. Use quotes and [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) properly. This works:

**so.txt:**

```
PRE 2022-03-16/
```

**test.sh:**
Note: `shellcheck test.sh` comes up clean now.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

awsdate="$(cut -c 5-14 so.txt)"
sysdates="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
echo "$sysdates"

if [[ "$awsdate" == "$sysdates" ]]; then
    echo "dates are matching"
else
    echo "dates are not matching"
fi
```

Cmd and output:

```sh
$ ./test.sh 
2022-03-16
dates are matching
```

Run `shellcheck` on your original script and see what it says for errors.

Here is what I see:

**Bad test.sh:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

awsdate= cut -c 5-14 so.txt
 sysdates=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
 echo $sysdates
 if [[ "$awsdate" == "$sysdates" ]] ;
then
    echo "dates are matching"
else
    echo "dates are not matching"
fi
```

Run `shellcheck` on it. I am using `shellcheck --version` of `version: 0.8.0`. These are all of your errors and problems:

```sh
$ shellcheck test.sh 

In test.sh line 1:
awsdate= cut -c 5-14 so.txt
^-- SC2148 (error): Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang or a 'shell' directive.
        ^-- SC1007 (warning): Remove space after = if trying to assign a value (for empty string, use var='' ... ).


In test.sh line 2:
 sysdates=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
          ^--------------^ SC2006 (style): Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticks `...`.

Did you mean: 
 sysdates=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)


In test.sh line 3:
 echo $sysdates
      ^-------^ SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: 
 echo "$sysdates"


In test.sh line 4:
 if [[ "$awsdate" == "$sysdates" ]] ;
        ^------^ SC2154 (warning): awsdate is referenced but not assigned.

For more information:
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2148 -- Tips depend on target shell and y...
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1007 -- Remove space after = if trying to...
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2154 -- awsdate is referenced but not ass...
```

### References:

1. my notes on `shellcheck`: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/tree/master/bash#shellcheck